# Calculation issue on self incremention

Tags: pine-script, auto-increment, pine-script-v5

I've this issue in my script code.
The abc indicator each bar is a sum of value of abc on previous bar + the value of formula volume*(close - close[1])/close[1]

I don't undrstand why plotting abc I've alway zero value

```
//@version=5
indicator("myscript")
var abc = 0.0

abc := abc + volume*(close - close[1])/close[1]    
plot(abc, title="abc")
```

Any ideas and explanation for this behaviours?

Comment: Might be helpful to tag this question with a language.

Comment: I suppose volume might be zero and that results in abc equals zero. Check it out on another symbol.

Comment: Volume is not zero.br/
abc := volume*(close - close[1])/close[1]   done a correct plot
abc := abc + volume*(close - close[1])/close[1]   return always zero

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the first bar, close[1] is `NaN`. Summing NaN `abc` value with non-`NaN` values on the next bars will result in `NaN` anyway.

Start calculation from the bar_index 2 or use `nz()` function to replace `NaN` with zeros.

```
//@version=5
indicator("myscript")
var abc = 0.0

abc := abc + nz(volume*(close - close[1])/close[1])    
plot(abc, title="abc")
```